# how to strip symbols after make but before make install?

Tags: makefile, workflow, symbols, stripping

I have a big project which after make ends up with 1GB of executables and libs.
I use standard workflow: `autogen, configure, make, make install`. The problem is after this all the files ends up in default system directories along with other installed software and I can't selectively use strip to reduce the size of the project's executable and libraries. What is a proper **workflow** to strip symbols after `make` is done? Are there options for this in `configure` other then visiting each source directory and do it on my own after `make` is over?

Comment: `make LDFLAGS+=-s` will allow the user to strip stuff as part of linking (or rather, it will if their linker supports the option).

Comment: A better option might be using **install**'s `--strip` option.  This retains the debugging data in the resulting executable.

Answer (score 0):

### make cmd

replace

```
make install
```

by

```
make install-strip
```

maybe that's want you want.
It will call `install` with `-s` option to strip binary when install.

### the install-strip target

[GNU: Standard Targets for Users](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#:~:text=%E2%80%98-,install%2Dstrip,-%E2%80%99)